# Worklight Java adapter invoke another adapter get I/O issue

Tags: adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a issue when I try to call adapter (HTTP/MYSQL) from a Java adapter.

When I am using Postmen test it (added Authorization on the header) 
It's always get a IO issue:

`[I O: Invalid token on line 1, column 14]`.

First, I guess it should be OAuth issue, I add `@OAuthSecurity(enabled=false)` at the class but not work.

Would you please help me find out where the problem is.

Code snippet:

```
DataAccessService service = WorklightBundles.getInstance()
            .getDataAccessService();
ProcedureQName name = new ProcedureQName("mysqlAdapter",
            "getMysqlAdapters");
String para = ""; // String para = "['a','b','c']";
InvocationResult mysql= service.invokeProcedure(name, para);
JSONObject jsMysql = mysql.toJSON();
//String rst = jsMysql.get("key").toString();
```

PS following code snippet is working when I test it on Postman:

```
HttpUriRequest request = api.getAdaptersAPI()
            .createJavascriptAdapterRequest("mysqlAdapter", "getMysqlAdapters");

try {
    HttpResponse response = api.getAdaptersAPI().executeAdapterRequest(request);
    JSONObject jsonObj =api.getAdaptersAPI().getResponseAsJSON(response);
    return jsonObj.toString();
}
catch (MFPServerOAuthException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return "error";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am confused...

1. You use the tag "worklight", but the Product Worklight 4.x-6.2 does not have Java adapters support. There is JavaScript adapters support and the ability for a JavaScript adapter to call Java code on the server. There is also the ability to call a JavaScript adapter from Java code - but not do be confused as a Java adapter.
2. *Java* adapters exists only starting *MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0* (formerly called "Worklight", tag is "mobilefirst"). I mention this because you've mentioned OAuth support, which was introduced alongside Java adapters in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0. But this has got nothing to do with any of your code snippets. a Java adapter looks nothing like that.

So,

- If you are using Worklight, you cannot use any of that OAuth stuff.
- If you are using MobileFirst, you shouldn't call your adapters this way at all. Please review the Java adapters tutorial and first create a proper Java adapter: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/adapter-framework-overview/

Also note that at this time it is not easily possible to call a Java adapter from a JavaScript adapter (the opposite way of your request, if it is to be understood correctly).

Comment: Thanks @Idan, I am using mobilefirst and JAVA Adapter. Thanks your replay and I think I'd better re-read the doc again...